# Best way to compare list elements

Tags: java

I have a list of Strings `List<String> treeList`. I want to compare the lists last four elements with a predefined string for each respective element. What's the best way of doing that?

One approach that I thought is

```
String firstParent = treeList.get(treeList.size() - 1);
String secondParent = treeList.get(treeList.size() - 2);
String thirdParent = treeList.get(treeList.size() - 3);
String fourthParent = treeList.get(treeList.size() - 4);

if(firstParent.equals("a") && secondParent.equals("b") && thirdParent.equals("c") && fourthParent.equals("d")) {
     return true;
}
```

Is there any less typo methods available? list comparison can be for 2 , 3 or 4 elements.

Comment: Since you want to compare each 4 last elements to a different string, I would say that any attempt to condense the code would make it actually harder to read, so worse. I'd say keep the naive way for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can grab a sublist and compare it to your own list of values:

```
List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
List<String> actual = treeList.subList(treeList.size() - 4, treeList.size());
if (actual.equals(expected)) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What if `treeList.size() - 4` returns a negative value?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Why are you asking me? Ask OP.

Comment: treeList.size() - 4 can not be negative. This is ensured by calling function.

Comment: If the `expected.size()` would be 3, the IndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Just as in OP's approach. Obviously that wasn't a concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a String comparison from Strings derived from a List, first ensure the List has enough elements, or you will get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. When comparing Strings it is always good to make sure the first value that is checked is not null, so I would change the calls to .equals() as well...

`if(treeList.size() >=4 && "a".equals(firstParent) && "b".equals(secondParent) && "c".equals(thirdParent) && "d".equals(fourthParent)){
    //    etc...
    }`